# How to properly format numbers in EF code-first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have a model like this:

```
public string ProductId { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N6}")]
public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
```

If using `N6` as the dataformatstring, the result is:

- `4321` is displayed as `4.321,000000`
- `5667,5443` is displayed as `5.667,544300`

I don't want to add the decimal if the price is fix (int). But if the price has decimal value, it doesn't matter.

For example:

- `1234` is displayed as `1.234`
- `4321` is displayed as `4.321`
- `433.8778` is displayed as `433.877800`

Advice, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the exact output you are looking for, but you can try working with following...

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Here the 0:0.00 defines the length of the decimal point and you can control the number anyways you want.

Comment: Hi, how about the thousand separator? If it is like that, the `int` value will display the decimal too.